# Return big HTML block with some php without make string

Tags: php, html, return

How can i return big html block with some php by using `<<<HTML HTML;` .

```
    return <<<HTML
<div>Here some text</div>
<?php thisFunctionEchosomthingNotReturn(); ?>
<?php if($isflag){?>
<span>DO not do this</span>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $whatever; ?>
HTML;
```

I can't understand what will work and what will not! how should i use this kind of return `<<<HTML HTML;` block with some php variable that i need to echo and some function that echo some thing (not return)

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors, so this will never work.  Never put php tags inside a heredoc statement.  See me answer. It should help.

Comment: You may consider learning to use a php templating library. They can make it easier to format lots of output. Which one to use? Oh dear, where to start? let me count the ways... ;-/ [Comparison_of_web_template_engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'capture output' for this task. see **[Output Control Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)**

i has some example code that i have just tested. It captures the output of the **div** tag in $out1 and shows it again later.

This technique is used in many 'templating' libraries and in 'views' in the 'frameworks'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Test of Output control functions</title>
</head>

<body>
 <?php ob_start(); // capture the buffer ?>
    <div style="border: 4px solid red">
       <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
       <p>This is test PHP code: <?php echo time(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php $out1 = ob_get_contents(); // end capture ?>

</body>
</html>


<?php  echo $out1;  // output now or save for later. ?>
<?php  var_dump($out1, strlen($out1));  ?>
<?php exit; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, google heredoc syntax for PHP.

but this is how it works (which I think you are trying to do.

```
$html = <<<HTML

<div>
     <h1>$phpVariableTitle</h1>
     <div>
       {$thisFunctionEchosomthingNotReturn()}
     </div>
</div>

HTML;
return $html;
```

Try that.  IMPORTANT! heredoc syntax requires your closing tag be left aligned with no tabs.  So make sure there are no spaces or tabs to the left of your heredoc tags, in this example my heredoc tags are called HTML.  Also, wrapping your php variables/functions with curly braces is optional but good practice for this method. NO PHP tags in side heredoc block.

Hope that helps.

To make a conditional statement work inside you need to use a function:

```
class My_Class {
  public function myCondition($param) {
      if($param === true) {
         return '<p>True</p>';
      } else {
         return '<p>False</p>';
      }
   }
}
$object =new My_Class();
$html = <<<HTML
   <div>
       <h1>Conditional Statement</h1>
       <div> {$object->myCondition(true)} </div>
   </div>
HTML;
```

something like that should work. But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Please can you tell me how can i use if else or loop in HEREDOC ?

Comment: You can't. You can use heredoc inside a loop though.  if($condition === true) { //CONDITION 1 HEREDOC GOES HERE } else { //CONDITION 2 HEREDOC GOES HERE }

Comment: Or you can have a conditional statement in a function and call the function inside the HEREDOC syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but here in your example the myCondition function return some html but in my case my function not returning it echo some html, so its not working what should i do ? please help me.

Comment: I advise you pickup a book on PHP, looks like you are a beginner. (Not trying to be insulting, that is how all of us learn this stuff).  Simply add echo $html;  to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write control structures / functions logic inside of `HEREDOC` syntax.

Alternate way..

```
<div>Here some text</div>
<?php thisFunctionEchosomthingNotReturn(); ?>
<?php if($isflag){?>
<span>DO not do this</span>
<?php echo $whatever; }?>
```

Comment: Then what should i do? how should i return html and php function that echo some html too?

Comment: You know PHP can be embedded into HTML right ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Comment: Yes, but i have a situation here. i need to return a big html block. but there some function that not return they echo some html code.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand your question properly may be this may help:

```
<HTML>
<div>Here some text</div>
<?php thisFunctionEchosomthingNotReturn(); 
if($isflag){?>
<span>DO not do this</span>
<?php }//Closing If if it ends here.
echo $whatever; ?>
</HTML>
```